# How do I import and use a NPM package to a Vue.js application?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, npm

I've tried to import [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitalets/google-translate-api) package to my Vue.js app, but nothing worked.

I want to use this package to translate a text content from `<input>` html tag.

This is the `<input>` in `HelloWorld.vue` file:

```
 <input class="input" placeholder="Type your text here" />
```

I've imported in `main.js` file with:

```
import "@vitalets/google-translate-api";
```

And looks like it worked, but how can I use the package with my `<input>` text content?

Comment: Read the documentation from NPM that you linked to. Does not work from a web page context, because translate.google.com does not provide CORS support. The package is specifically for use with NodeJS.

Comment: I suppose you may get the text content from your input and send it to your backend asynchronously to translate via this api. Than get translation result back and show it in your HelloWorld component.